# Como criar um modelo a partir de outro modelo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu tenho dois modelos. Um chamado User e outro chamado Professional, onde:

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :professional
accepts_nested_attributes_for :professional
end
```

e

```
#professional.rb
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Minha regra de negócio diz que todo profissional vai ser um usuário. Logo, toda vez que eu cadastrar um profissional, eu preciso, automaticamente, criar um usuário e atribuí-lo ao respectivo profissional. No meu *ProfessionalsController*, na ação de *new* e *create* eu fiz o seguinte:

```
#Professionals_controller.rb
class ProfessionalsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @professional = Professional.new
    @professional.build_user
    respond_with(@professional)
  end

  def create
    @professional = Professional.new(professional_params)
    @professional.save
    respond_with(@professional)
  end
end
```

O problema é que dessa forma não consigo consigo criar o usuário do profissional no momento da criação do profissional. Eu consigo salvar o profissional normalmente, mas não é criado nenhum usuário pra ele e nem atribuído o seu respectivo *user_id*.

O que estou fazendo errado ? Algum conselho para esse tipo situação?

Answer (score 1):

Você verificou se no método create a variável `professional_params` possui os parâmetros do User? Eles serão necessários para a criação do usuário.

Você está usando o model User na view `new` do Professionals? Se não estiver acho que um caminho melhor é colocar a criação do User no método `create` e remover a chamada  `@professional.build_user`.

Answer (score 1):

Se User has_one Professional, então Professional tem um campo user_id. Se quiser você pode inverter a ordem da associação, e utilizar o accepts_nested_attributes em um modelo. Uma alternativa para o seu problema seria:

Modelos:

```
class Professional < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :professional
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for(@professional) do |p| %>
  <%= p.fields_for(@user) do |u| %>
    <%= u.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
class ProfessionalsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    professional_params #"professional"=>{"user"=>{"name"=>"John"}}
    user_params = professional_params[:user]
    user = User.create(user_params)
    professional = Professional.create(professional_params)
    professional.user = user
    professional.save!
  end
end
```